# Request for LaTeX notation?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, mathjax

I think this website needs LaTeX notation, and I'm guessing I'm not the only one with this feeling.

How can we ask StackExchange for that feature?

Comment: I was going to post the same request. :)

Comment: I actually made the same request, got the same message, googled for a bit to make it go away, and by the time I asked, I duplicated this.

Comment: It's also worth noting that this has been implemented on other Stack Exchange sites, notably math.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Relevant example: http://cs.stackexchange.com/q/3/26

Comment: @bitmask yep, that's my question :-)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

This has been turned on, so you should be good to go. (:

Comment: That was fast! Thanks.

Comment: Thanks! Is there a chance we can get it in the chat, too?

Comment: @Raphael no - we don't have this in chat.

Comment: Too bad. Would be useful when talking about subject related stuff. For other sites, too, I imagine.